# Mobile site - link to open google maps and set multiple markers?

Tags: google-maps, mobile

I know its possible to put multiple markers on a google map embedded into a web page. I also know its possible to make a link which when clicked in a mobile device will open the google maps app and set a marker.

However is it possible to crete a link which when clicked in a mobile device will open the goole maps app and set multiple markers? Thanks

Comment: do you want a static map, in other words, an image? or an embedded map, that you can interact with?

Comment: Interactive. Im talking about the google maps all that i think comes installed by default in iPhones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all your markers in a KML with google earth and put it somewhere on the cloud, and add a link to it (this link only works on iOS):

```
<a href="maps:q=http://example.com/mapdata.kml">
```

You should explore the idea of embed a [google map into the web site and put your markers your self programmatically.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#MarkerAnimations)